# 1 to 1 and 0 to 1

Tags: database, relational-database, entity-relationship

How would you model the relational data model for the following case?

```
leader is chosen to lead group
a group is led by one and only one leader
a leader leads 0 to 1 group
```

This is my solution

```
Group [GroupID(PK)]
Leader[LeaderID(PK)]
Leads [GroupID(PK), LeaderID(FK)]
```

But this actually allows many leaders to lead a group.

Thank you. Any input is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you could just have `leaderOf` as a (unique) field in the `Leader` table. If it's `NULL`, the leader doesn't lead any group, and if it's a number then that number is the ID of the group being led.

If you have a `users` or `players` table somewhere, it might even be better to put that `leaderOf` field in that table and drop the `Leader` and `Leads` tables altogether.

Comment: hmm. But I could have 2 leaders with the same leaderOf.

Comment: Oh. How do I show an unique field in a relational model representation? Leader[LeaderID(PK), LeaderOf(FK & Unique)]

Comment: The group has to know it's leader too. Otherwise there could be groups without any leader and condition #2 would be violated

Answer (score 0):

Just let the group know its leader and the leader know its group.

```
Group [ GroupID(PK), LeaderID(FK) not null ]
Leader[ LeaderID(PK), GroupID(FK) ]
```

Comment: Leader -0-|----------------|-|- Group This is not M:N!

Comment: M:N? _Your_ solution is a M:N-relation! But that's _not_ what you want, is it? Anyhow, I improved my answer a bit..